# How to see exactly what happend in git merge

Tags: git, merge

I'm in

branch_X

I do

```
 git log -p  lib/foo
```

to see differences in the file foo, but the interesting thing I want to see is just written as:

```
commit aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Merge: bbbbbbbb cccccc

   Merge branch 'branch_X' into branch_Y

   Conflicts:
       lib/foo
```

How can I see exactly what happend in this merge?
Something bad seems to have gotten inserted into branch_X during this merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to view the differences that were merged in which you can do with:

```
git diff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa^ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Although looking at the message: "Merge branch 'branch_X' into branch_Y", it sounds like the merge was done the other way around. Either way you might want to look at the merge the other way around and see what the differences to the second parent were:

```
git diff aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa^2 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
The command
     `git diff aaaa^2  aaaa`
showed me the lines

`+   bad code`
`-   correct code`

I'm just a regular git (no git-EXPERT) so git diagnostic is way over my head, so I must ask:
How should I interpret this result? What has happend here? 
I don't follow you when you say "the other way around".

If you could explain a little bit more I'd appreciate it very much.
Again, thank you.

Comment: @JanneH: You've merged two branches so you can view it is merging X into Y or as Y into X. I don't know your project so I don't know if one of these is a more naturally way of viewing the merge or not. Either way the two diff commands will give the the view of what changes were brought in by the merge against each of the two parents.